# vb.net service, start a process as a local (current) user?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

With a vb.net Service, how do you start a process as local (current) user?  I found the ProcessStartInfo.Username Property, but it required a username and password.  I just want it to start as the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Services are intended to be started before a user logs in, which is why you need to provide credentials.  The service is started prior to there being a "current" local user.

If you want to make the program start as the current user, you should just make it a console or windows application instead of a service.

Comment: OK, that makes sense now, thank you.  See, I am splitting up a windows application into a GUI and a Service, since part of the application has to have admin privileges, but the GUI does not.  So I figured I would just run that small part that needed admin privileges as a service, and then start the GUI from the service.  I suppose I should just create a start up registry entry for the GUI?

Comment: @DannyBoy You won't be able to start the GUI from the service.  A common approach in this case is to build the service, and have the GUI app run either on demand (when the user wants to) or on user's login and just use IPC to connect.  (The service will be running prior to login)